# Painfully slow encoding popup with "temp file" when creating new file

Tags: character-encoding

Around half the time (and I haven't established a solid repro that triggers it), opening a new file in emacs will trigger a big pause, then two windows appear: one showing `*temp file*` and one asking me to choose encoding for the temp file. This is on a beefy windows 10 machine with windows 25.1.1.

[image]

I'm running on prelude and mostly use projectile, but it happens outside of projectile and I've cleared projectile's file list. Emacs has been rebooted multiple times.

Anyone know how I can stop this? Maybe I need to manually clear this temp file, but where does it live?

Comment: The first thing to check is if this happens in an emacs -Q environment. Does the "file" utility report the encoding for these files?

Comment: this file that can't be encoded is the \*temp\* file, and I can't find anything on where that lives (if it's even an on-disk file)

Comment: I'm assuming the *temp file* is an interim buffer that emacs creates to encode the file you just opened. Is there any reason to think it is unrelated to the file you just opened?

Comment: it previews the temp file in the top-right of my screenshot, and that's not what I'm opening. I'm just opening a regular code file, not a huge list of other files.

Comment: also it doesn't seem consistent - the incident I had this morning was opening a file I've opened swiftly multiple times in the last few weeks, and has no non-ascii chars.

Comment: do you recognise any of the stuff in the temp buffer? Could it be flycheck/flymake results being triggered by a change to the file you are opening? Can you trigger the problem with emacs -Q?

Comment: yeah, they're definition files from my projects. I have no solid repro so I've messed around with -Q and not seen it, but that isn't a strong endorsement and I'm not using -Q _all day_. I guess I'm going to have start chopping stuff out of my config, aren't I?

Comment: Running M-x describe-mode while in the temp buffer may give you a clue as to what is messing with it.

Comment: Try `M-: default-directory` in buffer `<*temp file*>` to see where emacs wants to save that file. The directory name may even give a clue on the source of that buffer.

Comment: I can't break out of the helm pop-up to get into the displayed temp window. It only appears during file opens, then goes away.

Comment: I don't have helm. But maybe `M-: (global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") #'recursive-edit)` and `M-: (setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)` helps. Hopefully you can escape helm by entering recursive edit via function key f5. Go to the temp buffer and investigate it. When you are done input `M-x exit-recursive-edit`.

Comment: recursive edit did nothing for me - `helm-get-nth-action: No such action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This continued, with variations, for years. It didn't happen on my other machines that sync'd the same dotfiles.

I finally fixed it by deleting a bunch of the files under ~.emacs.d\savefile. Will update if the problem comes back.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

- You're calling `find-file` or similar.
- You have some kind of custom completion framework installed which is kicking in automatically at this point in order to present you with a selection of files to choose from.  (Based on the screenshot, this is presumably `helm`).
- The framework is using this `*temp*` buffer to process its data.
- One or more of your files contains one or more funky characters in its filename.

The warning buffer gives you an interface for inspecting the characters with encoding issues, which will surely take you to the filenames in question, which will give you some more information/context about why and when this issue occurs, and allow you to provide a recipe to reproduce the issue.

Armed with that recipe, you could then pose the question upstream to the maintainer of the framework in question.